# What is the parameter estimated for the eqn $y = \theta * x$ using OLS

Tags: linear-regression

I have tried to estimate value for the $\theta$ parameter in equation $y = \theta * x$ using OLS. What I obtained is

$$\theta = \sum_i(y*x)/\sum_i(x^2)$$

Am I correct in the formulation. PLease suggest.

Comment: Are they all vectors? I have very little information from this question. What are you summing over?

Comment: I have just two columns of which one is x and the other y is predicted output.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for the reply :). Will this change if I introduce an error term to my main equation?. I hope not.

Comment: @Devi. If you only consider errors on $y$ (the classical OLS), this is correct.

Comment: Ok...thank u again :+1

Answer (score 1):

*Just to clarify.*

The model being $y=\theta x$, based on $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$, in the OLS sense you need to minimize
$$SSQ=\sum_{i=1}^n(\theta x_i-y_i)^2$$ COmputing the derivative with respect to $\theta$, then $$\frac{dSSQ}{d\theta}=2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(\theta x_i-y_i)$$ and you want this to be zero. Forget the $2$ and expand
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(\theta x_i-y_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i\theta -\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i=\theta\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i -\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i=0$$ and then your formula.

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: Is OLS estimation for linear regression iterative ?

Comment: @Devi. Not at all ! Doing the same for any model which is linear with respect to parameters, it is just immediate.

Comment: Thanks a lot!... Would you mind going through https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309940/how-can-dickey-fuller-test-give-ve-value-for-t-stat

Comment: @Devi. When I read things like the link, I understand (once more) that I am a Martian ! Sorry about it but I am very ignorant is this area (just as in many other). Cheers.

Comment: Ok...thank u for the support so far

Comment: What can be the coefficient value here $ \Delta X_t = \alpha + p*X_{t-1} +\epsilon_t$. Will there be a change in answer ?